# Invalid cast with dapper and decimal(10,2)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, dapper

The following code give me invalid cast operation.
The Qty column in my MS Sql server is of type `decimal(10,2)`

```
#region SQL Syntax

var sql = "select qty from productarticle where articleid=@articleid and productid=@productid";

#endregion

using (IDbConnection cn = Connection)
{
    cn.Open();

    return cn.Query<double>(sql, new { articleid = articleid, productid = productid }).Single();
}
```

If I try to return it as `int`, there is no problem.
Any clue?

Answer (score 6):

[SQL decimal maps to C# decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cc716729.aspx), not double